# Form does not redirect to action url if there is a validation error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a problem with uri action in laravel.

When I submitted the form, it redirects to the full url if it is successful. But if there is an error, it remains to the current url address.

example:

The current URL is : http://localhost:8000/test?url=test_sample

and my form looks like below:

```
<form action="{{ url('test?url=action') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="file" name="pdf_file"> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

If the above form contains an error, it will just remain to `test?url=test_sample` url. If it is successful, it redirects to `test?url=action`

**EDIT**

**Controller**

```
class MyFormController extends Controller
{
   public function uploadfile(Request $request)
   {    
       $this->validate($request, [  
           'pdf_file' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:5000'
       ]);

       return 'uploaded';
   }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/test', 'MyFormController@uploadfile');
```

I need this feature to take effect on my site.

Does anybody know?

Comment: What is your question? How to do it or are you having some issue? What have you tried? You need to show us your controller as well, since it's there the logic happens (unless you're using JS to validate and submit?)

Comment: I want to redirect to uri in action which is `test?url=action` whether successful or not.

Comment: Then i don't get the problem? The above should post to that URL regardless? What happens in your controller?

Comment: Edited now. please see. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you're using (`http://localhost:8000/test?url=test_sample`) contains a `url` parameter. To use this parameter in the controller, you need to get the value from the `$request` object injected into the `uploadfile()` controller method:

```
$request->get('url');
```

You can use it to redirect the user from the `uploadfile()` controller method after processing the upload:

```
public function uploadfile(Request $request)
{
    // ... 
    return redirect($request->get('url'));
}
```

Because you're using the `validate()` method in the controller method, the request will *automatically redirect back* if the validation fails. You can replace this with manual validation to handle the result yourself:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'pdf_file' =>  'required|mimes:pdf|max:5000',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect($request->get('url'))
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    return redirect($request->get('url'));
```

**Edit** - I think I misunderstood part of your question. It doesn't look like you want to use the `url` parameter in the controller method. If not, just change the validation statement.

Comment: wow.. thank you.. cool. one question, how to display the error on blade since you used `withErrors`?

Comment: By default, Laravel injects the `$errors` variable into your blade templates that contains any validation errors. There's a lot you can do with it. See [the validation docs](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).